# New columns not saving in rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, sqlite

I am creating an online store application using rails and when the user processes an order I initially created an order scaffold with columns:

- :name, :text
- :address, :text_field
- :email, :email

This worked fine and the form would submit and all data would be added to the database. However I wanted to add two new columns to the database, delivery_date and delivery_time so I created a migration and added them via

- add_column :orders, :delivery_date, :text
- add_column :orders, :delivery_time, :text

Next I went into the _form partial and added new lines into the form_for method to now look like

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :delivery_date %>
  <%= f.text_area :delivery_time %>
</div>
```

But when the form loads and I enter information into these two new fields it doesn't get saved to the database, when I use sqlite3 to select * from orders i get

```
id = 1
name = name entered
address = address entered
email = email entered
delivery_date = 
delivery_time =
```

I don't know if I have to add these column information anywhere else? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller you need to permit those attributes to be passed via params. Look for method called `order_params`.

Answer (score 3):

In your rails controller class, in the method that handles the submission of the form, are you using a secure method of binding the submitted values to the ActiveRecord object? For example, if you do something like this:

```
def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    @person.save
end

def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :address, :email)
end
```

Then you just need to add the additional parameter names to the list of permitted param names. For example:

```
def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :address, :email, :delivery_date, :delivery_time)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add it to attr_accessible if you are not using rails 4.

```
attr_accessible name, address, ... , delivery_date, delivery_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of `strong parameters` which was introduced in Rails4 to solve your issue.

It gives you control to make a conscious choice of which attributes should be permitted to be mass updated in database. 
In your case, as you generated your `scaffold` of order using 3 attributes `name, address and email`, rails generator created a ready made private `order_params` method for you in the `OrdersController` and permitted these 3 attributes for you.

But when you generated a migration with 2 new attributes, rails generator is just going to create a migration file for you and not update the `order_ params` method for you with these 2 new attributes. If you want these two attributes `delivery_date and delivery_time` to be updated in database then just permit them in `order_params` method. That should solve your problem.